# Rebol grid control

Tags: datagrid, rebol

I am looking for an equivalent of a grid control in Rebol, to display some table data.

I came across this script: [face-grid.r](http://www.codeconscious.com/rebsite/rebol-library/face-grid.r)

...and its associated demo: [face-grid-demo.r](http://www.codeconscious.com/rebsite/face-grid-demo.r)

This seems to be an excellent start.  Does anyone know if there is some active and/or newer version of this grid, or something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending what you need exactly.
Brett's datagrid is a bit basic. For example, it does not handle scrollers by itself.

Henrik has done a list-view with tons of features. Maybe it can be a choice for you :
[list-view](http://www.hmkdesign.dk/project.rsp?id=list-view&page=info).

But there are also different list styles part of the *VID extension kit* from the same author.
[Here](http://www.hmkdesign.dk/project.rsp?id=vid-ext-kit&page=docs&section=user&name=vid-extension-kit-lists.txt) is the list documentation.

All are for Rebol2.

Comment: I am going to have a look.

Comment: Cool, although I'm seeing an impending rift in the Q&A as these aren't  Rebol 3 solutions and it seems certain that there will never be an open source Rebol 2.  :-/  You can help @pierre out to get the 20 rep to join chat with an question upvote!

Comment: There is a specific R3 (or rebol3) tag. I'm not certain there'll ever be a chasm. Although R2 and R3 implementation of things will diverge in significant ways—the core principle I don't believe will change. That is, you might need different scripts to do the same thing, to a user of R2 or R3, the actual code will not look all that different.

Comment: Very good tool, thank you! It will certainly fit my needs, and I do recommend it to whoever share such needs.

Comment: I have tried it in rebol2, obviously. At the moment, as far as I know, VID is only implemented in rebol2, so...

Comment: R3GUI exists and is available in the source code form for quite some time.

Comment: At the time I tried to run R3GUI, it did not work in GNU/Linux, though. It is a bit of a shame, I thought: one of the greatest strengths of Rebol2/View was to be incredibly multiplatform, especially in GUI stuff.